# Using the "use" command in PHP with Composer packages

Tags: php, composer-php, goutte

I have tried to install two different composer packages and call them using the "use" command as mentioned in the docs, i am running on wamp64 localhost.

The error which occurs when trying to access the file through the browser is:
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Goutte\Client' not found in C:\wamp64\www\crawler\index.php on line 5

The composer package i am trying to use is:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

This is the current index.php file:

```
<?php

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/');
```

I followed the docs perfectly however the error still returns.

Comment: have you included composer's autoloader?

Comment: Could you show us a snip of your php before and after line 5 of index.php? Or actually, just the whole top of it till line 7ish.

Comment: Hi guys, i have just updated the question, thanks for the quick replies @IncredibleHat

Comment: Yup, you need to `require` the `..wherever/vendor/autoload.php`... wherever it is. Kind of odd their docs didn't mention how to include it.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, the solution was this line of code:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it or this question hangs around.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to this line of code to the top of the index.php file: require 'vendor/autoload.php';